# How to clear the data in recyclerview when relaunch the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have scrren 1 which display form to select a branch.. then we press submit we open screen 2 which display all items in selected branch from screen 1 .. screen 1 & screen 2 are fragments.

The problem now is when i return back from screen 2 to screen 1 and change the branch then i resubmit .. the list of items in screen 2 displays items from previous selected branch first then display items from new selected branch under it .. it is something like caching the data but with adding new data also !!

i tried many ways but i can't find where the issue

This is my code to open screen fragment 2 when re-submit:

```
CarsFragment fragment = new CarsFragment ();

            fragment.setArguments(args);
            ((MainActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

I tried to remove fragment on destroy view but with no point !

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    }
```

How to fix that or i have to convert it to activity??

This is my all code of fragment screen 2 :

```
public class CarsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, OnNetworkListener, ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<Car> {

    private CarsViewModel carsViewModel;
    private FragmentCarsBinding mBinding;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final String TAG = "CarsFragment";
    public static CarsAdapter carsAdapter;
    private Snackbar snack;
    private NetworkChangeReceiver mNetworkReceiver;
    private final int PAGE_ROWS = 25;
    private int currentView = 1;    // list = 0 , gallery = 1 , mapView = 2
    private int city1Id = 0;
    private int city2Id = 0;
    private int city1Type = 0;
    private int city2Type = 0;
    private Long receiptDateTime;
    private String daysNum;
    private int customerType;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    private String branchesIDs;
    private String makersIDs;
    private String categoriesIDs;
    private int minModel;
    private int maxModel;
    private String kms;
    private String rentTypes;
    private int minPrice;
    private int maxPrice;
    private String ratings;

    private ClusterManager<Car> mClusterManager;
    private ArrayList<Car> favList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> favNumber = new MutableLiveData<>();
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    private boolean isLoading = false;
    private boolean isLastPage = false;
    private List<Car> carList;
    //    private int TOTAL_PAGES = 5;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    Bundle args;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = requireActivity().getIntent();
        Log.e("onCreateView", "22222");
        if (intent != null) {

            city1Id = intent.getIntExtra("receiptPlace", 0);
            city2Id = intent.getIntExtra("deliveryPlace", 0);
            city1Type = intent.getIntExtra("receiptPlaceType", 0);
            city2Type = intent.getIntExtra("deliveryPlaceType", 0);
            receiptDateTime = intent.getLongExtra("receiptDateTime", 0);
            daysNum = intent.getStringExtra("daysNum");
            customerType = intent.getIntExtra("customerType", 0);
            lat = intent.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0.0);
            lng = intent.getDoubleExtra("lng", 0.0);


        }

         args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {

            city1Id = args.getInt("receiptPlace", 0);
            city2Id = args.getInt("deliveryPlace", 0);
            city1Type = args.getInt("receiptPlaceType", 0);
            city2Type = args.getInt("deliveryPlaceType", 0);
            receiptDateTime = args.getLong("receiptDateTime", 0);
            daysNum = args.getString("daysNum");
            customerType = args.getInt("customerType", 0);
            lat = args.getDouble("lat", 0.0);
            lng = args.getDouble("lng", 0.0);

            branchesIDs = args.getString("branchesIDs", "");
            makersIDs = args.getString("makersIDs", "");
            categoriesIDs = args.getString("categoriesIDs", "");
            minModel = args.getInt("minModel", 0);
            maxModel = args.getInt("maxModel", 0);
            kms = args.getString("kms", "");
            rentTypes = args.getString("rentTypes", "");
            minPrice = args.getInt("minPrice", 0);
            maxPrice = args.getInt("maxPrice", 0);
            ratings = args.getString("ratings", "");

        }


//        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        carsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(CarsViewModel.class);
        carsViewModel.setFragment(this);
        mBinding = FragmentCarsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        Log.e("onCreateView", "1111");
//        carList.clear();
        initViews();
        Utility.showProgressDlg(getContext());
        carsViewModel.loadCars(city1Id, city2Id, city1Type, city2Type, String.valueOf(receiptDateTime), Integer.parseInt(daysNum), customerType, lat, lng, PAGE_ROWS, currentPage, branchesIDs, makersIDs, categoriesIDs, minModel, maxModel, kms, rentTypes, minPrice, maxPrice, ratings);
        mNetworkReceiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
        mNetworkReceiver.setOnNetworkListener(this);
        carList = new ArrayList<>();
//        carList.clear();
        getCars();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mBinding.carsListView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mBinding.carsListView.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            protected void loadMoreItems() {
                isLoading = true;
                currentPage += 1;
                carsViewModel.loadCars(city1Id, city2Id, city1Type, city2Type, String.valueOf(receiptDateTime), Integer.parseInt(daysNum), customerType, lat, lng, PAGE_ROWS, currentPage
                        , branchesIDs, makersIDs, categoriesIDs, minModel, maxModel, kms, rentTypes, minPrice, maxPrice, ratings);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLastPage() {
                return isLastPage;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLoading() {
                return isLoading;
            }
        });
        mBinding.favRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (favNumber.getValue() > 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(requireActivity(), FavActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        favNumber.postValue(0);
        favNumber.observe(requireActivity(), number -> {
            mBinding.textNotify.setText(String.valueOf(number));
        });

        return mBinding.getRoot();
    }

    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu) {
        try {
            MenuItem map = menu.findItem(R.id.mapView_badge);
            if (map != null)
                map.setVisible(Constants.IS_CARS_MAP_VIEW_ENABLED);
            super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onPrepareOptionsMenu: ", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
//        menu.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.gallery_view_badge:
                if (currentView == 1 || currentView == 2) {
                    carsAdapter.setList(true);
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_gallery_view);
                    if (currentView == 2) {
                        mBinding.carsListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mBinding.carsMap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    currentView = 0;

                } else {
                    currentView = 1;
                    carsAdapter.setList(false);
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_table_view);
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.mapView_badge:
                if (currentView != 2) {
                    mBinding.carsListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mBinding.carsMap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    setUpMapIfNeeded();
                    mapFragment.requireView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    currentView = 2;
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_gallery_view);
                } else {
                    mBinding.carsListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mBinding.carsMap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    currentView = 1;
                    carsAdapter.setList(false);
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_map_view_white);
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.filter_badge:
                FilterationFragment fragment = new FilterationFragment ();
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void initViews() {

        mBinding.basicFilterTl.addTab(mBinding.basicFilterTl.newTab().setText(requireActivity().getString(R.string.near_to_you)));
        mBinding.basicFilterTl.addTab(mBinding.basicFilterTl.newTab().setText(requireActivity().getString(R.string.low_price)));
        //mBinding.basicFilterTl.addTab(mBinding.basicFilterTl.newTab().setText("Best Seller"));
        mBinding.basicFilterTl.addTab(mBinding.basicFilterTl.newTab().setText(requireActivity().getString(R.string.newest)));
        for (int i = 0; i < mBinding.basicFilterTl.getTabCount(); i++) {
            View tab = ((ViewGroup) mBinding.basicFilterTl.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(i);
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) tab.getLayoutParams();
            p.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 0);
            tab.requestLayout();
        }
        mBinding.basicFilterTl.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        Collections.sort(carList, (car, t1) -> car.getKm().compareTo(t1.getKm()));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Collections.sort(carList, (car, t1) -> car.getPriceDaily().compareTo(t1.getPriceDaily()));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Collections.sort(carList, (car, t1) -> t1.getCarModel().compareTo(car.getCarModel()));
                        break;
                }

                carsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        snack = Snackbar.make(requireActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_connection), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    }

    private void usingMapCluster() {
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<Car>(requireActivity(), mMap);
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
        mClusterManager.setRenderer(new CarRenderer(mMap, mClusterManager, getLayoutInflater(), requireActivity()));
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(mClusterManager);
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this::onClusterItemClick);
        mClusterManager.addItems(carList);

        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        if (carList.size() > 5) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                builder.include(carList.get(i).getPosition());
            }
        } else {
            for (Car car : carList) {
                builder.include(car.getPosition());
            }
        }
        mClusterManager.cluster();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 12));

    }

    private void getCars() {
        if (isNetworkAvailable(requireActivity())) {
            carsViewModel.carsMutableLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), cars ->
            {

                Log.e("getViewLifecycleOwner", String.valueOf(cars.getListOfData().size()));
                if (cars.getListOfData().size() == 0)
                    isLastPage = true;
//                carList.clear();
                carList.addAll(cars.getListOfData());
                setAdapter();
                isLoading = false;
            });
        } else {
            showSnackBar();
        }

    }

    private void setAdapter() {
        if (carsAdapter == null) {
            carsAdapter = new CarsAdapter(requireActivity(), carList);
            mBinding.carsListView.setAdapter(carsAdapter);

            carsAdapter.setOnCarItemClickedListener(this::addItemToFav);
        } else {
            mBinding.carsListView.post(() -> {
                carsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(carList.size() - 1);
            });
        }
    }

    public void showSnackBar() {
        snack.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.red));
        snack.show();
    }

    public void hideSnackBar() {
        snack.dismiss();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Get the map and REGISTER for the ready callback.
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.cars_map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this::onMapReady);

            mapFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.cars_map);

            onMapReady(mMap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        setUpMap(mMap);
    }


    public void setUpMap(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        this.mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
        mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
        mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        if (carList != null && carList.size() > 0) {
            usingMapCluster();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkConnected() {
        hideSnackBar();
        // getCars(3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkDisconnected() {
        showSnackBar();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        registerNetworkBroadcastForNougat();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        requireActivity().unregisterReceiver(mNetworkReceiver);

    }

    private void registerNetworkBroadcastForNougat() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requireActivity().registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(Car item) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        CarInfoPopupFragment.newInstance(item).show(ft, "CarInfoPopupFragment");
        return true;
    }

    private void makeFlyAnimation(ImageView targetView) {

        LinearLayout destView = mBinding.favRelativeLayout;

        new CircleAnimationUtil().attachActivity(requireActivity()).setTargetView(targetView).setMoveDuration(1000).setDestView(destView).setAnimationListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        }).startAnimation();

    }

    private void addItemToFav(Car car, ImageView imageView) {
        boolean isAdded = false;
        mBinding.favButtonIV.setBackground(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_heart_on));
        if (favList.size() > 0) {
            for (Car mCar : favList) {
                if (mCar.getCarKindId().equals(car.getCarKindId())) {
                    isAdded = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    isAdded = false;
                }
            }
            if (!isAdded) {
                makeFlyAnimation(imageView);
                favList.add(car);
                favNumber.postValue(favNumber.getValue() + 1);
            }
        } else {
            makeFlyAnimation(imageView);
            favList.add(car);
            favNumber.postValue(favNumber.getValue() + 1);
        }
        SharedPref.putPrefFavLists(requireActivity(), favList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
//        carList.clear();
//        carsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Fragment f = this;
        this.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.getView().requestFocus();
        this.getView().setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
            {
                if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
                {
                    Log.e("cleeeaar", "dekdjeojdoe");
                    carList.clear();
                    carsAdapter.removeList(carList);
                    carsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mBinding.carsListView.setAdapter(carsAdapter);

                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();

                    Log.e("cleeeaar222", "dekdjeojdoe");
//                    carsAdapter.removeList(carList);
//                    carsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        } );

        favList = SharedPref.getPrefFavList(requireActivity());
        if (favList.size() > 0) {
            mBinding.favButtonIV.setBackground(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_heart_on));
        }
        favNumber.postValue(favList.size());


    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        Log.e("fragmentonpause111", "kfrjfj1111");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        Log.e("fragmentonpause", "kfrjfj");
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a static instance of the adapter?

Comment: no it is not static >> private CarsAdapter carsAdapter;

Comment: if you can show some code of the fragment, we can help

Comment: i have editmy question and added all the code of the fragment which display items of the branch

Comment: help pls .. it takes me long time to fix it

Comment: from where you are getting the list of cars, an API?

Comment: yes exactly .. from api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227422/discussion-between-rahat-and-eng-ahmed).

Comment: ok sent you now